# Convert datetime obj to timezone-aware datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following date I am trying to save:

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_raw, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

When I save it, I get the following Warning:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808:
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime
(2014-12-11 21:42:58) while time zone support is active. RuntimeWarning)
```

How would I convert my datetime object to a tz-aware datetime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides a [utility function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone) for this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

timestamp = make_aware(timestamp)
```

By default this will use the [current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone), which by default is `TIME_ZONE`. If that's not what you want you can pass the desired timezone as an argument to `make_aware`.